# BackboneJS, MarionetteJS - Trying to display layout + regions

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I've got the following code

```
$ ->

  class MainLayout extends Marionette.Layout
    template: Handlebars.compile $("#main_layout_hb").html()

    regions:
      header    : "#header"
      options   : "#options"
      footer    : "#footer"


  class MainRegion extends Marionette.Region
    el:"#main_wrap"

  class App extends Marionette.Application

    main_region : new MainRegion
    main_layout : new MainLayout

    onStart: =>
      @main_region.show(@main_layout)

      # start the backbone history for URL routing
      if Backbone.history
        Backbone.history.start()


  app = new App
  app.start()
```

I'm trying to follow the example on this page https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/The-relationship-between-regions-and-layouts

But when I run the code, I don't get the template "#main_layout_hb" inserted into the region. What's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your App's region using the addRegions method:

```
App.addRegions
    main_region: "#main_wrap"
```